# Angular Material 2 Datatable headers not aligned right

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have set the styles for header cell and cell to be aligned right but headers are not aligned only the cell text

Here is a link to a [sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qwmx2y?file=main.ts)

I have added

```
.mat-cell, .mat-header-cell {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`text-align: right`  doesn't work with `display:flex` element, and here you're trying to applying `text-align` property on `mat-header-cell`' elements `mat-sort-header-container` class. You could use below to fix your issue.

```
::ng-deep .mat-header-cell .mat-sort-header-container {
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

[**Forked Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qwmx2y-iaht2n)

Comment: thanks that works. But when using it as a directive this trick does not work

Comment: @pantonis can you reproduce this issue in stackblitz. So I can dig more, if that's the case..

Comment: ah sorry forgot to menton that I edited the original link above with the directive

Comment: You should be adding a class to `mat-sort-header-container` which is child element of the directive DOM

Comment: So I cannot use directive?. The reason I need it is becuase some headers need to remain as they are and some to be aligned right

Comment: Can you update the example please in order to understand?

Comment: any news on this one?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.  I added the following to the css:

```
.mat-column-columnname {
    text-align: right;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

And changed the location of the sort arrow to before the label:

```
<th mat-header-cell mat-sort-header arrowPosition='before' *matHeaderCellDef>
```

Comment: adding arrowPosition='before' on header this pushed the header to the right